# Unable to check cups printer status in Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, bash, printing, cups

Sorry for my english!

I'm using Debian squeeze and for an assignement, i have create 2 virtual pdf cups printers. Both are working very well.
To test the different administion command; i try to disable one of the printer and move his queue file to the second one. I'm able to do it easily.

Now, i wish to write a bash script that wil test the status of the printer. So that,if the printer is disable, it just execute the "move" script.
Is there a way to know the status of a cups printer and use that information in a script?

For example, a command/function that can return "O" is the cups printer is enable and "1" if not.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Have you tried using lpstat command?

Answer (score 1):

As Andrei mentioned, you should be able to use the lpstat command to handle this.  Specifically, try parsing the output of:

```
lpstat -p
```

Under normal circumstances, you'll get something like:

```
printer HP_DESKJET_940C is idle.  enabled since Mon 09 Aug 2010 10:42:20 PM CDT
printer HP_LaserJet_1012 is idle.  enabled since Mon 09 Aug 2010 10:36:26 PM CDT
```

When something is wrong with one of the printers, the "idle" text will change.  I recommend playing around with the states of your virtual printers until you get the output you want.  For your bash script, maybe you want something like this:

```
lpstat -p | grep -E 'HP_DESKJET.*\(idle|printing\)' >/dev/null || false
```

This sequence of commands will test whether your printer is in the idle or printing states, and if it is not, then it will produce an exit code of 1.  Otherwise, it will produce an exit code of 0.  Of course, you will want to adjust the name of your printer and the available states to your project's needs.